# PWA on iOS: Notification.permission return default whatever we chose

Tags: ios, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, web-push

Since the release of PWA and webpush notifications by apple on iOS I implemented it in my app but I face a problem.

In the app I use Notification.permission to know if the user activated the push notifications. Basically the behaviour should be:
return "Denied" do not display anything
return "allowed" do not display anything
return "default" display a message "Do you want to activate the notifications"

But on iOS, if I agree to have the notifications, then I go to another page Notification.permission is back to default.

It does not have an impact on the notification which are received well but the user will be always asked if he wants to activate them.

Is it a turnaround on ios to know if the permission has been granted which does not change after changing page?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you describe is clearly a bug. The only solution is to report it to Apple: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: Yep that's what I did. Waiting for a fix I used a localstorage value to save it

Comment: @Tartempion34

I have more or less the same issue. For me it's when I open the PWA from a notification, then it thinks that the permission is "default" again, while it's working fine right after I asked for permission. However, when I close (not minimize) the PWA and open it again from a notification, the problem is gone forever.  Did you ever get an answer from Apple about this bug?

Comment: Same here. It reverts back to "default". I already have a check if it is "granted" or not.